# Invalid operands to binary * ( have 'char *' and 'char *' )

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, c-strings, cfstring

Here is my code:

```
NSString *string    = @"Ciyt";
const char *City    = [CityString UTF8String];
CFStringRef value   = CFSTR(&City);
```

show following error at third row in Xocde:

> Invalid operands to binary expression  ( 'char *' and 'char *' );

Any idea to resolve it?

Comment: Wrong language tag. Is this Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

CFSTR is a macro that only works with string literals, like CFSTR ("abc").

Comment: YES, I find the CFSTR description in apple document :
Creates an immutable string from a constant compile-time string. 
CFStringRef CFSTR ( const char *cStr ); 
cStr 
A constant C string (that is, text enclosed in double-quotation marks) from which the string is to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve here, but if you want to convert an `NSString` into a `CFString` you can do this directly without going via a C string thanks to [toll-free bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html):

```
NSString *string = @"Ciyt";
CFStringRef value = CFBridgingRetain(string);

// use value...

CFBridgingRelease(value);
```

Here's a screenshot of the Variables View showing the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks,  Steve Wilford.  I just try to use CFSTR and a C string instead CFSTR and text enclosed in double-quotation marks to create a CFString, but it doesn't work

Comment: Why are you even trying to use `CFSTR` though? If you want a `CFString` use the method I have described.